# Able to ping websites but gui programs have no Internet access

Tags: wifi, networkmanager

The internet in my area went down today and on coming back up I am experiencing wired and WiFi Internet connectivity issues.

The connection manager applet shows me as connected and I am able to ping google.com (for example) but the various programs I use, Firefox, Dropbox, liferea, thunderbird etc cannot connect to Internet.

I have tried resetting via network manager restart, nmcli networking off and a few other commands I have forgotten.

Any ideas how I resolve this?

Edit: using a Virgin hub 3.0 router. Wireless adaptor is qualcomm atheros ar9485. I also use one fo those tplink WiFi extenders but even if I stand right next to router it doesn't work.

I had connection issues with my work machine which runs windows after Internet came back on but that appears to have resolved itself now.

Edit 2: reinstalled network manager and not good. Pretty close to doing a clean reinstall.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include details of equipment used between your PC and the external internet?

Comment: I added info on equipment.

Comment: Maybe you have Citrix Workspace App installed?

Comment: I assume you've tried rebooting the router, followed by a reboot of the wifi extender?

Comment: No, yes and yes.

Comment: *but the various programs I use, Firefox, Dropbox, liferea, thunderbird etc cannot connect to Internet.* What do they report as error?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani just "unable to connect" or similar.

Comment: The thing is, your DNS might be failing, or your connectivity. The error messages are different and so might be the solutions. That's why it is important to know *how* it fails. Maybe add the output of the `ping` and then the output of `wget wttr.in`.

Answer (score 1):

It just started working now without me doing anything (had pretty much given up). I may never know what caused it.

Thanks to everybody who replied.